# Android Development java.cert.certpathvalidatorexpaction error https

Tags: java, android

I have a simple code for downloading .pdf documents from a website.
It ist working very well for http sites , but for my https site it
wont download any ! I become an java java.cert.certpathvalidatorexpaction 
error in my logcat.
Please tell me how to trust all https sites oder special this one.

Sorry for my bad english, im german :)

Here is the Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // button to show progress dialog
    Button btnShowProgress;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ImageView my_image;
    // Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0; 

    // File url to download
    private static String file_url = "https://www.example/test.pdf";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // show progress bar button
        btnShowProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgressBar);
        // Image view to show image after downloading
        my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
        /**
         * Show Progress bar click event
         * */
        btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // starting new Async Task
                new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Showing Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            return pDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to download file
     * */
    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread
         * Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                // Output stream
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.pdf");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
       }

        /**
         * After completing background task
         * Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);


            String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.pdf";
            // setting downloaded into image view
            my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Android developer docs](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonProblems) have something on how to properly set up HTTPS trust managing. I'm guessing you use self-signed certificates? Basically, you have to set up your own `SSLSOCketFactory` with a `TrustManagerFactory` that "knows" how to trust your self-signed certificate. It sounds scary, but is actually not too bad. It works like this:

```
// Load the truststore that includes self-signed cert as a "trusted" entry.
KeyStore truststore;
truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
InputStream in = getActivity().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.truststore);
truststore.load(in, "Your Password".toCharArray());

TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(truststore);

// Create custom SSL context that incorporates that truststore
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

Put your truststore.bks under /res/raw for this to work. Note that you **must** use [Bouncycastle version 1.46](http://www.bouncycastle.org/fr/download/bcmail-jdk15-146.tar.gz) for this to work - any newer and you'll get a versioning error from Android.

As a side note, if you research the topic on google/SO, one advice you'll find fairly regularly is implementing a trust manager that will simply trust all certificates.

***DON'T DO THIS*!!!** I can't stress this enough. Don't. It's super easy, but it's bad advice. It's like putting in a door and then taking the lock out because you don't want to bother with having to use a key. If your data is so security-insensitive that disabling trust checking is a viable option for you, then just use an HTTP connection. Using HTTPS with disabled certificate checking is just giving users a false sense of security.

Comment: okey, now i have my truststore.bks under res/raw in my android app. But where i have to copy your code ? in my mainactivity on the top? sorry T am a newbie. I see your from germany ? maybe we could talk german :))

Comment: The code goes into the setup of your connection, so between `url.openConnection()` and `connection.connect()`. And yes, I'm from Germany, but I think we should stick to English so other SO users can benefit as well. :)

Comment: okey right , I tried to fix my connection error when i put your code in mine but i faild. What does the connection in the last line does ?

Comment: I think you have mispelled connection (it's missing an n in your code, so I have `connection` but you have `conection`...they need to both be the same). Also, you need to change your line `URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();` to `HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();` After that does it work? (`f_url[0] needs to start with "https:" or you'll get an error.)

Comment: my error in my code is gone but now, after I debuged my app on my Phone there are lots of errors and after i clicked the button i become a force close. My Debug window tells me that there is an error with doinbackground. I post my log:                       03-20 13:19:42.453: E/AndroidRuntime(26652): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
`03-20 13:19:42.453: E/AndroidRuntime(26652): Process: com.example.test2, PID: 26652
03-20 13:19:42.453: E/AndroidRuntime(26652): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()` @chris

Comment: 1. Please indicate the cause of the exception (where it says "caused by" in the stacktrace. 2. From giving your code a quick look-over, you need to change `InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);` to `InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream(), 8192);`

Comment: 3. I think you should read the javadocs for [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), [HttpsURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) and [this official guid](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) before doing any more work on your project

Comment: Okey, caused by : `03-20 14:28:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(25373): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
03-20 14:28:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(25373):  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
03-20 14:28:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(25373):  at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:232)
03-20 14:28:56.153: E/AndroidRuntime(25373):  at com.example.test1.MainActivity$DownloadFileFromURL.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:192)` Thanks for your advice, I will have a look :) @chris

Comment: I'm _guessing_ you're getting an exception without an error message that trips the `Log.e` call in your catch block. Replace it with this `Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage() != null ? e.getMessage() : e.getClass().getSimpleName());` That will output either the exception message if there is one, or else the class name of the exception. Then check your logcat and see what's happening.

Comment: okey , I found out that the error is happening when the number is 0 in this line    `URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);` I believe its a simple error with a simple fix or ? @chris

Comment: What number is 0? Btw, I think since your original problem (the CertPathValidatorException) is solved, you should probably open a new question. The problem you're having now has nothing to do with CertPathValidatorException any more.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Chris has written, if your servers are not using self signed certificates, note that Android has root certificates for most of well known certification authorities so most of the  connections work just fine. CertPathValidation failure usually means client is not able to establish chain of trust and link all the server certificates together. If your server is using CA certificates, you should also check if certificate chaining is complete and correct using OpenSSL or tools like Portcle.